# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 project and PCL library error VS 2013 U2 RC issue

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013, resharper

Recently I converted my WP8 project to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1. The project references some PCL utility library. Everything compiles and runs fine but I'm getting a lot of warning (underscored code) in the IDE [image]

I also tried to create simple WP Silverlight 8.1 project which uses pcl library but i still have the same issue.

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 2 RC with Resharper 8.2 plugin.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to read the text of that image. Could you please copy the error as text and include it in your question?

Comment: @WiredPrairie you can right-click on the image and open it separate tab (in original size)

Comment: Your popup image is still clipped, so it's impossible to determine what's actually going on. Consider posting your issue to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: Same problem discussed [here](https://twitter.com/gblock/status/461414113629843456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've uninstalled Resharper and now warnings are gone, so it looks like plugin issue. They're working on new update (8.2.1)